# wxPython update StaticText every x seconds/minutes using timer

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm trying to update some static text using a timer and the output of a function.

The code is here: [code](http://pastebin.com/xqgx6b4W).

I know very little about wxPython, it's one of the many things that I just don't *get* and this is maddening, if I print the output of apper to console it works perfectly, all I want to do is have what prints out to the console applied to the text.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Timers can be a pain to use, an easier way is to use the functions `wx.CallAfter` and/or `wx.CallLater` - also these functions are thread-safe and can be used to invoke functions on the GUI thread from other worker threads. Here is a sample...

```
import random
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Frame, self).__init__(None)
        self.SetTitle('Title')
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        style = wx.ALIGN_CENTRE | wx.ST_NO_AUTORESIZE
        self.text = wx.StaticText(panel, style=style)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)
        sizer.Add(self.text, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.on_timer()
    def on_timer(self):
        self.text.SetLabel(str(random.randint(0, 100)))
        wx.CallLater(1000, self.on_timer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Frame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: This will keep calling and updating until i close the program?

Comment: Yes. In `on_timer`, `wx.CallLater` is used to schedule another call to that function in one second (1000 milliseconds).